# Using Elastic Search to Query inside arrays in CouchDB

Tags: php, rest, lucene, couchdb, elasticsearch

My CouchDB database is structured like this:

```
"custom_details": {
  "user_education": [
    {
      "device_id": "358328030246627",
      "college_name": "College",
      "college_year": "2014"
    },
  ]
}

"custom_details_1": {
  "user_education": [
    {
      "device_id": "358328030246627",
      "college_name": "College",
      "college_year": "2014"
    },
  ]
}
```

I have a lot of arrays within arrays.  What I'm trying to do use Elasticsearch to search and find terms, regardless of where it's sitting in an array.  Is that possible?

I've been going through the examples on [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/) and haven't quite found what I'm looking for.  I've tried using **Elastica, the PHP Wrapper**, but without fully understanding how to do this with REST, I'm lost.  Is it even possible to search for data without knowing the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lucene, you could create a document instance for each device id:

```
public void indexRecord(CouchDBRecord rec) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("device_id", rec.device_id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("college_name",  rec.college_name, Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("college_year", rec.college_year.toString(), Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    this.writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

This will allow you to search by keywords in the college name, or by exact device id or year, or some combination thereof.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Elastica, the whole REST thing is already done for you. If you want to search in all fields, you can define just the search term and it will search in all fields.

If you are having some troubles with Elastica or if some features are missing you need, let me know, as I'm the developer of Elastica.

Comment: hi Nicolas Ruflin i am working on elastic search with couchdb . i have a little bit confusion , how can i manage index for multiple users at a time .

Comment: for one user at time its working perfectly, but when i tried it for multiple user at same time it was having warning (org.apache.commons.httpclient.SimpleHttpConnectionManager getConnectionWithTimeout WARNING: SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly. Be sure that HttpMethod.releaseConnection() is always called and that only one thread and/or method is using this connection manager at a time.)